# Datatable LWC - Lookup Field

Tags: lightning-web-components, lookup, lightning-datatable

I stuck with adding the lookup field into my Datatable component. I have two lookup fields AssetId and PricebookEntryId. I want to make AssetId clikcable, and PricebookEntryId editable.

I created Custom Data Type and Custom Lightning Datatable, I want to add it into my datatable. But I don't know how to retrieve the lookup field.. Do you have any documentation or example how can I achive that?

My Datatable:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getWOLIs from '@salesforce/apex/woliControllerDatatable.getWOLIs';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import delSelectedWoli from '@salesforce/apex/woliControllerDatatable.deleteWolis';

import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import Serial_No__c_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/WorkOrderLineItem.Serial_No__c';
import Quantity_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/WorkOrderLineItem.Quantity';
import PricebookEntryId_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/WorkOrderLineItem.PricebookEntryId';
import ListPrice_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/WorkOrderLineItem.ListPrice';
import AssetId_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/WorkOrderLineItem.AssetId';
import Discount_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/WorkOrderLineItem.Discount';
import TotalPrice_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/WorkOrderLineItem.TotalPrice';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/WorkOrderLineItem.Id';

const actions = [
     
     
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete'}
];

const COLS = [
    {
        label: 'Device',
        fieldName: AssetId_FIELD.fieldApiName,
        editable: false
    },
    {
        label: 'Serial No.',
        fieldName: Serial_No__c_FIELD.fieldApiName,
        editable: false
    },
    
    {
        label: 'Product',
        fieldName: PricebookEntryId_FIELD.fieldApiName,
        editable: true
    },

    { label: 'Quantity', fieldName: Quantity_FIELD.fieldApiName, editable: true },
    {
        label: 'List Price',
        fieldName: ListPrice_FIELD.fieldApiName,
        type: 'double',
        editable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Discount',
        fieldName: Discount_FIELD.fieldApiName,
        type: 'percent',
        editable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Total Price',
        fieldName: TotalPrice_FIELD.fieldApiName,
        
        editable: false
    },
    
    {
        type: 'action',
        typeAttributes: {
            rowActions: actions,
            menuAlignment: 'right'
        }}
];
export default class WoliDatatableLWC extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    columns = COLS;
    draftValues = [];


    // non-reactive variables
    selectedRecords = [];
    refreshTable;
    error;

    // retrieving the data using wire service 


    @wire(getWOLIs, { woId: '$recordId' })
    wolis;
    

    handleRowActions(event) {
        let actionName = event.detail.action.name;

        window.console.log('actionName ====> ' + actionName);

        let row = event.detail.row;

        window.console.log('row ====> ' + row);
        // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
        switch (actionName) {
            case 'delete':
                this.deleteWolis(row);
                //break;
        }
    }

    async handleSave(event) {
        // Convert datatable draft values into record objects
        const records = event.detail.draftValues.slice().map((draftValue) => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draftValue);
            return { fields };
        });

        // Clear all datatable draft values
        this.draftValues = [];

        try {
            // Update all records in parallel thanks to the UI API
            const recordUpdatePromises = records.map((record) =>
                updateRecord(record)
            );
            await Promise.all(recordUpdatePromises);

            // Report success with a toast
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Work Order Line Item updated',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );

            // Display fresh data in the datatable
            return refreshApex(this.wolis);
        } catch (error) {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error updating or reloading work order line items',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }
    }

    deleteWolis(currentRow) {
        let currentRecord = [];
        currentRecord.push(currentRow.Id);
        this.showLoadingSpinner = true;

        // calling apex class method to delete the selected contact
        delSelectedWoli({lstWolIds: currentRecord})
        .then(result => {
            window.console.log('result ====> ' + result);
            this.showLoadingSpinner = false;

            // showing success message
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success!',
                message: currentRow.LineItemNumber +' Work Order Line Item deleted.',
                variant: 'success'
            }),);

            // refreshing table data using refresh apex
             return refreshApex(this.wolis);

        })
        .catch(error => {
            window.console.log('Error ====> '+error);
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error!!', 
                message: error.message, 
                variant: 'error'
            }),);
        });
    }
    handleSuccess() {
        return refreshApex(this.wolis);
    }
}
```

Custom Data Type:

```
    import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class CustomTypeA extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @api customValueA;

    fireCustomTypeA() {
        let newCustomValueA = this.customValueA + 1;

        const event = new CustomEvent('customtypea', {
            composed: true,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            detail: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                newCustomValueA: newCustomValueA
            },
        });

        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Custom Lightning Datatable:

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable'
import customTypeA from './templates/customTypeA'
import customTypeB from './templates/customTypeB'

export default class CustomLightningDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
  static customTypes = {
    customTypeA: {
      template: customTypeA,
      typeAttributes: ['customValueA'],
    },
    customTypeB: {
      template: customTypeB,
      typeAttributes: [],
    },
  }
}
```

Apex Controller:

```
public with sharing class woliControllerDatatable {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<WorkOrderLineItem> getWOLIs(String woId) {
        return [
            SELECT Quantity, PricebookEntryId, Serial_No__c, TotalPrice,
                     Duration, ListPrice, Discount, WorkOrderId, Parent_WOLI__c, AssetId
            FROM WorkOrderLineItem
            WHERE Parent_WOLI__c = false AND WorkOrderId = :woId
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
        ];}
        @AuraEnabled
        public static void deleteWolis(list<Id> lstWolIds){
            try {
                list<WorkOrderLineItem> lstWoliToDelete = new list<WorkOrderLineItem>();
                System.debug('lstWolIds ====> '+lstWolIds);
                for(Id idWoli : lstWolIds) {
                    lstWoliToDelete.add(new WorkOrderLineItem(Id = idWoli));
                }
                if(!lstWoliToDelete.isEmpty()) {
                    delete lstWoliToDelete;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this link help https://www.pantherschools.com/how-to-use-the-lookup-field-in-lightning-datatable/

Comment: Hi! :) I tried to deploy it, but I am getting error: No MODULE named markup://c:searchComponent found : [markup://c:lwcDataTable]

Comment: have you created the LWC component with searchComponent and lwcDatatable name ? also if you are referring the document i provided, then that is only for referral, you need make required changes in your component accordingly.

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Comment: still in progress :) I will add the code when it will be ready. I need to also write query that user will see only records with the same company_code__c as user